# Facebook XFBML Like Button incompatible with FeatureLoader script?

Tags: facebook

Facebook gurus,

I have been implementing the Facebook Like button for a number of clients lately. To enable the Like Button, the following script has to be run:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '<?php echo Mage::helper("evlike")->getLikeConfig("ev_facebook_app_id") ?>',
         xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

It seems that this is incompatible with the following include:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It would make sense as I believe that the FeatureLoader performs an initialization. Is this official now? I would ask in official Facebook forums but I get an error every time I attempt to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect/Setting_Up_Your_Site

According to them: "Important: You need to reference the FeatureLoader script only once on a page. If you already have a Facebook Connect social widget on this page, you don't need to reference the FeatureLoader script again."

I would have been able to find that earlier but their wiki has been a real mess lately. Up, down, and all around.